# Python login script not working using sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I have made a python socket server and you need to login with an account that is linked to a text file with the format Username:Password:ID which works fine but in my code to figure out the issue I made it print out what username and password was used but when you type in the username it says this

```
Username: Admin
Password: Password

Admin

Password
```

Basically for some reason it is putting a new line above it changing the credentials put in, why? Here is the relevant code:

```
    def username(conn, prefix="Username: "):
        conn.send(prefix)
        return conn.recv(512)

    def password(conn, prefix="Password: "):
        conn.send(prefix)
        data = conn.recv(512)
        if data:
            return conn.recv(512)

    createLogin = file("login.txt", "a")

    with open("login.txt", "r") as login:
        lines = login.readlines()

    while True:
        username = username(conn)
        password = password(conn)
        conn.send("%s" % username)
        conn.send("%s" % password)
        for line in lines:
            if line.split(":")[0] == username and line.split(":")[1] == password:
                print("Do stuff")
        else:
            print("Failed")
            conn.close()
```

Just a reminder this works perfectly fine on localhost, it is when I run it on a VPS it breaks.

Comment: There is no client code here so it is unclear what the client is actually sending. Also, it is strange that you discard the first data received after the `Password:` prompt but maybe your unknown client sends the data like this.

Comment: Dude, you login using putty this is the server, this is the only relevant code you need. I discord the thing thing because for some reason it over laps username if I dont

Comment: If you login using putty there should be a newline after the username and password. But your code does not seem to deal with this newline. Hard to imagine that this works on localhost.

Comment: It does work on localhost just not a vps -_-